# Android media player - prompt user to select song then assign to button

Tags: android, media-player

My project has a button. What I'm trying to do is... Long clicking the button will prompt the user to select a song, and then anytime the button is normally clicked the song plays.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
        b.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                //Assign a song code here
                return false;
            }
        });
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.mysong);

                if( mPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mPlayer.pause();
                } else {
                    mPlayer.start();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue? this code would work fine

Comment: I don't know what to add to get the features described. There is a comment in the code where the new code should go.